# Need to connect a website to a database

Tags: php, html, database, hyperlink

I have a database full of phone specifications, I need the website to display in an already created html table, the specifications of the phone that the user has typed into the search box. I have HTML knowledge but have never linked a database to a website, can anyone recommend the best way to accomplish what i need? and any pointers that may help?
I have installed XAMPP and created the database in PHPmyadmin but have never used php before so have no clue where to start. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe begin with a tutorial like this? http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-connect-to-a-mysql-database-with-php-in-6-steps/

Comment: @markshh if your goal is to point users to a tutorial using depreciated functions which are also rendered useless compared to modern database APIs then your goal is complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create a `connection.php` and insert the following code:

```
<?php

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect("yourHost","root", "password", "databaseName");

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
}

?>
```

Step 2: When wanting to execute MySQL in a different file, say, `index.php`, use this:

```
include_once("connection.php");

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableName"; // This creates the SQL Query
        $query = mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql); // This executes it
```

From here on out it is just needing to know basic PHP that will allow you to do what you please with your website, but it is very important you learn PHP and a little bit of MySQL, good luck.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with you can use the following code but consider learning prepared statements or PDO.

```
<?php
//Make the connection to your database
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'your_password', 'your_database');
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error());
}

//Query the database
$query = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM your_table;";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
if(!$result) {
    die("SQL Error: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}
?>

<table>
    <?php //Fetch all the results ?>
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col1']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col2']); ?></td>
        <td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['col3']); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```